# PHPUnit codecoverage halts without reporting any error

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

When executing PHPUnit with codecoverage, the coverage generating just halts without any error, and no report is generated.

The problem is caused by a fatal error in one file, but it's hard to find what the error is without any error showing up.

I have confirmed `display_errors` is on, and I have set `error_reporting` to -1 in php.ini

After much testing with excluding files from coverage, I have found the file in error, and also what the error is (class not implementing inherited abstract methods), but this could have gone faster if I had an actual error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the PHPUnit config being used.

I had set error reporting like this:

```
<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="E_ALL & ~E_STRICT" />
</php>
```

I thought that should work, but it appears that you can only provide constants (`E_ALL`) or literal values, not expressions like that. This config will set error_reporting to `'E_ALL & ~E_STRICT'`, instead of the correct numeric value, causing all errors to be muted.

I have solved this by setting error_reporting in the phpunit bootstrap file.